# Custom HTTP headers using JPlayer

Tags: jquery, http, xmlhttprequest, jplayer

We are using jplayer (www.jplayer.org) to play some stream media on our system.

But, some HTTP requests for stream media requires custom HTTP headers.

There's a way to set manually HTTP Headers using JPlayer?

Regards,

And Past

Comment: i'm really struggling to understand your question.. will you state more clearly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I edited the post. Is this more clear, now? Regards

Comment: what technology does your streaming server use? Shoutcast? Windows Media Services?

Comment: I don't know which server will receive requests. We need to send change 'User-Agent' header and add some custom others fields, like 'X-Some-Control-Header-Key'

Comment: ok.. which browser are you using? Is your jPlayer using HTML5 Audio or the Flash fallback to stream the media? In either case, it is going to be tricky for you to modify the HTTP request headers..

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `headers` option on the `ajax()` function.

From the [jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)...

> **Headers** (added 1.5)
>   `Default: {}`
>   A map of additional header key/value pairs to send along with the
>   request. This setting is set before the beforeSend function is called;
>   therefore, any values in the headers setting can be overwritten from
>   within the beforeSend function.

Here's an example of how this would look...

```
$.ajax({
  url : "/script.php",
  type : "GET",
  headers: {
    "MyCustomHeader" : "Custom header value"
  }
});
```

Comment: This part I already did. The problem is not JQuery, but returning streaming load on jplayer. There's some way to deliver returning data to jplayer? Or, embed a custom function on JPlayer?

Comment: @apast you should spend more time writing your questions. You're wasting other people's time with your lack of clarity.

Comment: Sorry, @jessegavin. I'd edit the post expecting to be more clear and direct. Is it more clear?